# Error en MediaQuery en Angular 7 y Flex-Layout

Tags: angular

Estoy pasando un proyecto de Angular de la versión 6 a la 7, y me encuentro con un error al momento de compilar:

> ERROR in src/app/options/services/media-query.service.ts: error
>   TS2322: Type 'MediaQueryListEvent' is not assignable to type
>   'MediaQueryList'.

Estoy usando [Flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) y lo actualice en el package.json así:

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19"
```

Pero parece que algo más cambio porque en la versión 6 esto funcionaba muy bien.

Este es el código del servicio 'media-query.service.ts':

```
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

const LIMITE_ANCHO_MENU = 750;
const LIMITE_ANCHO_TITULO = 375;

export class MediaQueryService {
  private matcher: MediaQueryList;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone,             
              private mediaMatcher: MediaMatcher) {

    this.matcher = this.mediaMatcher.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${LIMITE_ANCHO_MENU}px)`);

    this.matcher.addListener(mql => this.zone.run(() => {
      this.matcher = mql;      
    }));
}
```

El error sale en la línea donde tengo la instrucción: `this.matcher = mql;`

Mil gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Mira [aquí](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/851) parece ser que `@angular/flex-layout` tiene un conflicto con `TypeScript` y deberías comprobar/ajustar las versiones instaladas

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar la linea

```
this.zone.run(() => { this.matcher = mql; }
```

por está y ya debería funcionar, son algunos cambios de angular.

```
zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${LIMITE_ANCHO_MENU}px)`)));
```

suerte crack